# Custom UIView rotation with a view controller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, rotation

I have an interface which consists of two views, which in landscape mode are to the left and to the right of the screen. Now when rotating to portrait, the views should be on top of each other and rotate themselves according to the device orientation (I hope the ASCII art helps to show what I mean, this should happen when the user rotates the device clockwise).

```
           -----
-------    | A |
| A B | => | B |
-------    -----
```

The screen itself should not rotate, only the views. I could probably solve this by swapping the views when auto rotating, but then there would be a visible break when I switch the views.

How would I go about it when I want the two views to rotate separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved something like this using animations in `viewWillRotateToOrientation:`. Essentially, the idea I had was to move the center of each view (or, in same cases, the frame) inside an animation that began when a rotation even was detected.

The difficulty with my approach is that I also needed to move the subviews around in `viewWillAppear` since the subviews didn't always get the message through `viewWillRotateToOrientation:` when they were moved off-screen or unloaded.

For the depiction you have above, you could just anchor the top left corner or A and the bottom right corner of B using the autoresizing masks (in IB or programmatically). However, if you want something more exotic, as I did, then try using animations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this is what I'm doing currently. But moving the center of the views makes one view "fly" over the other. What I would like to achieve is the impression of two views which are statically placed and rotate according to the device orientation.

Comment: Then I believe anchoring the appropriate corners is the way to go.

Comment: I tried this in a sample project and unfortunately does also not give the desired results. It actually works for one of the two views (since it's square) but the other would still have to be resized. I think for the effect I need I will have to manage the view transforms manually and disable autorotation on the view controller entirely. Don't know if this is the way to go though.